# Is it possible to get the size filled by a GridLayout?

Tags: c++, qt

In QtCreator, I used a form to draw a grid layout.  In my main window class, I added a `QGraphicsScene` wrapper object to this grid layout and am using the wrapper class to draw points onto the scene with mouse clicks.

What's happening is I'm clicking in locations that are negative relative to the `QGraphicsScene` wrapper, which is not the effect I'm going for, so I want to make sure I know the coordinates filled up by my `QGraphicsScene` and grid layout.

How can I get the size filled by the grid layout?  I'm currently doing something to this effect...

```
view = new QGraphicsViewWrapper();
ui->gridLayout->addWidget(view);

QGraphicsViewWrapper::QGraphicsViewWrapper(QWidget *parent) : QGraphicsView(parent)
{
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(50, 50, 350, 350);
    this->setSceneRect(50, 50, 350, 350);
    this->setScene(scene);
    this->setGeometry(QRect(20, 50, 400, 400));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I completely understand your aim but could you not do:

```
QRect size = ui->gridLayout->geometry();
```